# Android show Notification when app is not open?

Tags: android, notifications

Is it possisble to only display a notification to the user when the app is not active. (Open but not active). At the moment, i have the following code, which displays a notification. However it is also displayed when the user is in the app, and that is kind of pointless.'

```
public void notifyNewOrders() {
        sp.play(soundId2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
        int notificationId = 001;
        Intent viewIntent = new Intent(this, ListActivity.class);
        viewIntent.putExtra("01", "12");
        PendingIntent viewPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                viewIntent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.coffee_tea_icon)
                .setContentTitle("New Orders available!")
                .setContentText(
                        "New orders are available. Want to make some easy money?")
                .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent);
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat
                .from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Could i check if the activity is being viewed. And if not, display the notification? How can this be done. Thank you.

AS suggested. Is this correct:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    user_viewing = true;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    user_viewing = false;
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    user_viewing = false;
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        user_viewing = true;
    } else {
        user_viewing = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: use BroadcastReceiver for your requirement... google it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a boolean to store if activity is visible or not. 
ie. make it true in onCreate and onResume, make it false in onPause and onStop.
Then you can use this boolean for your test.

Comment: also, take into account onWindowFocusChange for cases when the app is active but hidden under the lock screen :)